# Pidgin auto-reconnect

Tags: networking, ubuntu, pidgin, instant-messaging

Using Pidgin 2.10.6 (libpurple 2.10.6) `4cfe697ea3ae39a4fb3dad8e3ed1c70855901095`

On Ubuntu 12.10 (yes I know this is out of support)

From time to time Pidgin will disconnect from a network. This could be the fault of the server, but more often is either my laptop or my office network. I don't really care about what's causing the drop outs.

What I do care about is that once Pidgin disconnects it just gives up, and I have to click manually reconnect. Every time. So if the connection drops for a minute I might not even notice, but Pidgin has thrown a strop and I'm off IM without realising it.

So, best case, I'd like a way to have Pidgin keep trying to connect, constantly. Even better would be that it at least checks whether my laptop thinks its on a network before doing so, but that's not an issue - I don't mind it banging its head against a brick wall. Again, if it can log when a problem starts that would be useful but not necessary.

If it can't be done then either - is there another similar messenger which has this feature? I'm using it for XMPP through Google Talk and Olark. Or at least can Pidgin notify me somehow that it's disconnected, such as an error icon in my system tray (using `gnome-classic`).